# Why I can't see bold,underline,italic codes in string in TextRange range

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

```
TextRange range;
FileStream fStream;
range = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
fStream = new FileStream("C:\\lol2\\joo.Rtf", FileMode.Create);
range.Save(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
fStream.Close();
```

It does everything correctly, but I cant see in range.Text \b for example. I need to manipulate bolded,underlined and italic text, so If there is \b before word I need to replace it to HTML tag . If I could collect the whole text to one string or certain words if they are formatted differently I could manipulate them

XAML:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="RichTextBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Im writing text inside WPF application and using controls to make words bolded etc.

Comment: Where can't you see '\b'? And what does HTML has to do with it? You have a FlowDocument, and you're saving it as RTF... Please clarify your question.

Comment: I cant see \b in debug mode inside range.Text. I just need to get the whole content from richtextbox with formats. Ifsome of the words is bolded I can put tags before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set like this:

range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);

Comment: Does not work, didnt show any \b before bolded words from richtextbox.

Comment: Maybe you should give us example as your source text that you are looking for different tags and trying to replace them.

Comment: I dont have that kind of source text because I cant get hold of words which are bolded